# Set class active upon selection

Tags: jquery, html

I want to set an attribute `class="active"` upon selection of a particular list. For eg when a a particular list is active, it should get active & when other is selected, that list should get active.
My current jQuery code sets all list as active upon selection of any item from the list. Instead i want only that item should be active which is selected.
How do I modify my jQuery code?

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked span5">
      <li class = "list"><a href="#" class="span3">abc</a></li>
      <li class = "list"><a href="#" class="span3">def</a></li>
      <li class = "list"><a href="#" class="span3">ghi</a></li>
      <li class = "list"><a href="#" class="span3">jkl</a></li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".span3").click(function () {
    $('.list').attr("class","active");           // sets all the list item active. Instead I want only that particular element to be active.

    });

});
```

Comment: check it out http://jsfiddle.net/hJYfu/2/

Comment: does it work with bootstrap...

Comment: No, it works partially. It does not de-select the previous selected elements upon selection of new elements.

Comment: something has been bothering me, now i get it. When few months ago i learned little bit of bootstrap i learned that In bootstrap, span3,span2 etc are used to set width of elements. Sooo many things could have span3 as their class and using it as selection point is bad idea. And probably breaks some js somewhere too. Try my new answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$(this).parent()` to get only the clicked on `list`, and it's easier to use `addClass` instead of `attr`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".span3").click(function () {
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    });
});
```

If you want all of the other lists to not be active as well:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".span3").click(function () {
        $('.list').removeClass("active");
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    });
});
```

Comment: Ho ShadowCat7, I tried this. Its not working. Any suggestions please. Upon selecting any item, its not getting active.

Comment: remove and add doesn't seem to be work together. Upon removing the `removeClass`, items get active, but the others dont get inactive(obviously).

Comment: Yesits working,since you defined a css file  but I'm using bootstrap. I know it should work on bot=otstrap as well, but unfortunately it is not.

Comment: I don't know why it wouldn't work, but I also don't know anything about bootstrap. Maybe you should update your question, or ask another? Either way, I am no longer of use to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can add class with this one:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".span3").click(function () {
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");    
    });    
});
```

and for remove class like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".span3").click(function () {
        $('.list').removeClass("active");    
    });    
});
```

See this in jQuery API Document [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

**UPDATE:**

Yep, i forget the parent()

Comment: He only wants one of the `list` elements active when clicked on; that adds `active` to all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery provides more functions. That nobody is using.

**Jquery Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".nav>li").click(function () {
        $(this).siblings('.active').toggleClass("active");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
});
```

Link : http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/hJYfu/3/ **NEW**

Pay attention to html structure.

Comment: what happens when you click something

Comment: It makes the class `active` but I have to click it again to de-activate it. Rather it should automatically get de-activated upon selection of new element.

Comment: Also, multiple actives are also there.

Comment: can you post a link to this page..or host it just to show me.

Answer (score 0):

Use addClass method instead of attr

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".span3").click(function () {
  $('.list').removeClass('active');
  $(this).parent().addClass("active");

  });

});
```

Comment: Partial solution. It does not make the previous list inactive upon selecting some other item.

Comment: Well, tried your updated solution as well. Still the same problem. ANy idea why?

Comment: Just updated again.. Use addClass instead of attr. Using attr removes the class 'list' from the list item. addClass just adds the class 'active' to it without removing 'list'

Comment: Well, initial I was able to set `active` using attr but now I'm not able to active any one of those.

Comment: remove and add doesn't seem to be work together. Upon removing the removeClass, items get active, but the others dont get inactive(obviously).

Comment: Letme write it on jsfiddle

Comment: It works just fine. Try adding some properties to the class 'active' to see the change when you click the link.
See here http://jsfiddle.net/T8SEJ/1/

Note the css I added in the css panel on the top right.